# Using Database table as Sharepoint data source with windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2010

Using Sharepoint Designer 2013, I'd like to add a data source that connects to a SQL server database.  Then, I plan to use a data view web part to edit data in the table.

The problem I have is Sharepoint designer requires that I enter a username and password when i create the data source.  I want each user to authenticate against the database using their Windows credentials so i can audit changes.  All our database permissions are granted via Windows groups.

Is there a way to connect Sharepoint to a database using the current user's Windows credentials?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to update data in external source the best approach in my opinion is to use Business Connectivity Services. You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx).